# Document library permissions don't matter

Tags: security

I've created a document library inside a SharePoint Foundation 2013 site. I have broken inheritance to the folder and assigned a single user.  However, everyone in the company can still access, modify, rename, delete, everything in the document library.  Doesn't make any sense.

I've even gone as far as removing everyone from the permissions of the document library, and it still allows everyone into it.

Thoughts ?

Comment: Did you after breaking inheritance, remove everybody from the that folder? if not then it is correct behavior...what permission level other user have( full control on library, site admin etc)

Comment: actually found the permissions of read-only for everyone in the centeral administration under the Web App.  once removed, sharepoint security took over.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things to check.

1. from site collection settings > site permission Check the Permission for the users.
2. Make sure Users are not with Full control or owner group
3. Check if Users are part of any group who have full control.
4. Also check from Central Admin Policy for Web Apps, if you added user there